# Encode binary data as ASCII in Java

Tags: java, encoding, ascii, bitset

I have a bitset of binary data that I wish to encode compactly as an ASCII string.  I intend to initially compress the data using run-length encoding to give a sequence of integers; e.g.

```
111110001000000000000111
```

becomes:

```
5o3z1o12z3o
```

(e.g. 5 ones, 3 zeros, 1 one, 12 zeros, 3 ones).

However, I wish to then compress this further into a compact ASCII string (i.e. a string using the full range of ASCII characters rather than the digits plus 'o' and 'z').  Can anyone recommend a suitable approach and / or 3rd party library to do this in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is compression, just gzip the stream. It's going to do better than your run-length encoding.

Then if you need it to be text for some reason, like to safely pass through old mail gateways, I'd also turn to a standard encoding like Base64, rather than make up your own.

But if you want to roll your own: first I'd note that you don't need the 'o' and 'z'. You already know those values since they alternate. Assume it starts on 0 (and if it doesn't, encode an initial 0 to show that there are 0 0s).

Encoding the numbers textually is possible but probably inefficient. Look into a variable-length encoding for integer values, then encode those bytes. Then 'escape' them into ASCII somehow.

But then we're back to Base64-like encoding, and the first suggestion to gzip + Base64 is probably easier than all of this.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check it out.  I notice there are non-public base64 encoders shipped in sun.misc.  BTW I included the 'o' and 'z' delimiters assuming that the sequence of 0s or 1s was of arbitrary length rather than a fixed size integer.

Comment: Commons Codec (http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has code to encode Base64. You can still have arbitrary-length integers without needing a full byte of delimiter between integers.

Comment: @Sean, if you were to encode arbitrary length integers without delimiters how would you know where one integer ended and the next one began?  Only thing I can think of is that you'd need to use a variable length encoding scheme (e.g. using the top bit of each byte to denote "has more bytes").

Comment: That's exactly how it's usually done. Google protobufs do this for instance, all the way back to the MIDI protocol.